# SQL Server : views, union different amount of row returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not that familiar with SQL Server and I'm a bit stuck here..

Combined View:

```
select * 
from dbo.Elen_SalesData_View
where EffectiveDate>='2013-12-01' and EffectiveDate<='2013-12-31'
```

returns 1319 rows.

`Elen_SalesData_View` structure:

```
SELECT     
   ItemCode, ItemDescription, ItemValue, Quantity, 
   CustomerId, CustomerName, SalesInvoiceId, EffectiveDate, 
   CountryId
FROM         
   dbo.Elen_SalesData_Historical

UNION ALL

SELECT     
    ItemCode, ItemDescription, ItemValue, Quantity, 
    CustomerId, CustomerName, SalesInvoiceId, EffectiveDate, 
    CountryId
FROM
    dbo.Elen_SalesData_Current
```

`Elen_SalesData_Current` in this instance will return nothing. So we are ignoring it..

`Elen_SalesData_Historical` consist of:

```
SELECT     
    CONVERT(varchar(30), ItemCode) AS ItemCode, Product, 
    CONVERT(varchar(60), ItemDescription) AS ItemDescription, 
    ItemValue, Quantity, ItemType, 
    CustomerId, CustomerName, 
    SalesInvoiceId, EffectiveDate, CountryId
FROM         
    db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch
```

returns 1319 rows.

Where `Elen_WinmanSalesArch` run as:

```
select * 
from Elen_WinmanSalesArch
where EffectiveDate>='2013-12-01' and EffectiveDate<='2013-12-31'
```

Returns 3489 rows - which is correct!

Why? And how to fix it please?

Maybe worth mentioning that `Elen_WinmanSalesArch` is querying to one database, while `Elen_SalesData_Historical` is run from another

---

Just ran a test:

```
select * from dbo.Elen_SalesData_Historical
where EffectiveDate>='2013-12-01' and EffectiveDate<='2013-12-31'
```

returns 1319 rows. `Elen_SalesData_Historical` is a view, and it's content is described above. But when i just run:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), ItemCode) AS ItemCode, Product, 
       CONVERT(varchar(60), ItemDescription) AS ItemDescription, 
       ItemValue, Quantity, ItemType, CustomerId, 
       CustomerName, SalesInvoiceId, EffectiveDate, CountryId 
FROM  db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch
where EffectiveDate>='2013-12-01' and EffectiveDate<='2013-12-31'
```

it returns 3489 rows! i'm really confused...

Comment: I may be missing something, but, are you saying that, when you select all rows from `dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch`, you get 1319 rows, but, when you select rows between certain dates from `Elen_WinmanSalesArch`, you get 3489 rows?

Comment: @zimdanen when i query to `Elen_WinmanSalesArch` i query from `db1` and when i query `dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch` i query from within `db2` which in turn runs a query from `db1`

Comment: `db1` and `db2` are databases?  How are you accessing `db1` from `db2`?  I don't see a third part to any of your table names..

Comment: @zimdanen i've added the full name to `Historical`: `FROM db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch`

Comment: I still think there is a confusion. So, `SELECT * FROM  db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch`, with no `WHERE` returns 1319 rows, but `select * 
from Elen_WinmanSalesArch
where EffectiveDate>='2013-12-01' and EffectiveDate<='2013-12-31'` returns 3489 rows?

Comment: @Lamak no, `SELECT * FROM  db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch` also returns 3489 rows

Comment: Then why is your question saying `SELECT     
    CONVERT(varchar(30), ItemCode) AS ItemCode, Product, 
    CONVERT(varchar(60), ItemDescription) AS ItemDescription, 
    ItemValue, Quantity, ItemType, 
    CustomerId, CustomerName, 
    SalesInvoiceId, EffectiveDate, CountryId
FROM         
    db1.dbo.Elen_WinmanSalesArch` returns 1319 rows?, can you clarify?

Comment: @Lamak I ran a test and updated my post....

Comment: Well, I think that you are just confusing the databases of your tables and views. Make sure of the database context where you are performing those tests, apend the database and schema to all of your queries

Comment: @Lamak well i achieved desirable result after getting rid of `Elen_SalesData_Historical` view and put a direct query as per my edit in `UNION ALL` statement - got all 3489 rows... i don't know why...